# Flutter app access different firebase project based on the location of the user

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, mobile, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `Flutter` app to be published in multiple countries (e.g. `US`, `CA`, `AU`, `NZ`, ..), and I am using `Firebase` as the backend.

Since one `Firebase` project is linked to one `region` only, once I've created a project and chosen the `region` for `firestore`, `functions`, `storage` ... , I cannot add another `region`.

But to ensure minimum latency and best performance, I need to make sure users are accessing the nearest `region`, thus US users accessing `US region`, AU to `AU region` and etc...

How to do that? is it similar to how you configure `prod` and `dev` environments?
Then when the app launches, it detects the country then choose an environment accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be possible
For prod and dev you have two firebase project, but for your porpuse you should have one prod firebase project per location, and i guess same for dev

If you really want this, you have to generate different apk with different google-services.json (This can be easier with flutter flavors) and config in playstore each location target per apk

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, you mentioned apk with google-services.json, which is Android, how about iOS app? can they do something similar?

Comment: Yep, with iOS you can also config flavors and different GoogleService-info.plis files
But to be honest, i don't know if in appstore you can select target location to release